# POST to PHP with success but PHP code not executing

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am using JQuery post method to send data to a PHP script from an external JS script.

```
const Url2 = 'MainPage2.php?action=updatePurchaseToDB';
   const data = {
       name: "test name"
   }
   //takes 3 arg, url, data to sedn, call back function, data in callback holds the page reqeusted in data
   $.post(Url2,data, function(data, status){
       console.log('${data} and status is ${status}');
       alert("PHP Retrned form server:  Status " + status);
   });
```

This is the PHP code in MainPage2.php :

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'updatePurchaseToDB'){
    echo "<script>console.log('UPDATE PURCHASE CALLED!');</script>";
    echo "PHP CALLED AS PURCHASE BUTTON PRESSED";
  }
```

The call back function returns a  *Success* message but I can't see any evidence the PHP code has executed, that is nothing has printed to the console.

Is there something missing in my call to the PHP script?

Answer (score 2):

Since the action is in the URL, you need to access it with `$_GET['action']`, not `$_POST['action']`. If you want it in the `POST` data, you need to add it to the `data` object:

```
const data = {
    action: "updatePurchaseToDB",
    name: "test name"
}
```

Your `console.log()` call is not substituting the variables correctly. You need to use backticks to create a template literal.

```
   $.post(Url2,data, function(data, status){
       console.log(`${data} and status is ${status}`);
       alert("PHP Returned form server:  Status " + status);
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that but still nothing printing to the console

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If you check the Network tab, do you see it sending the parameters and receiving the response? How are you calling the code in the first place?

Comment: No errors, console prints the commands from the callback; A success status and the data; the data returned is the Webpage contents

Comment: I thought you said nothing prints to the console.

Comment: I was referring to the print to console commands in the PHP code I am trying to send data to, sorry should of been clearer

Comment: You need to use backticks around the string in `console.log()` to get the variables substituted.

Comment: Tried: echo "<script>console.log(`UPDATE PURCHASE CALLED!`);</script>"; still nothing printing to console so  am uncertain the code is been executed

Comment: How are you calling this code? Is it part of submitting a form?

Comment: No it’s via the JQuery Post, the aim, ultimately, is to send an Array of data from a JS function, to the PHP code, in order to update a database

Comment: I see the jQuery post, but I'm wondering how you call the jQuery post? Is it something like `$("#form").submit(...)`?

Comment: Make sure you prevent the default form submission if you're using AJAX instead.

Comment: Hi, the JQuery POST is called in a JS function in an external .js file. The JS function is called when a user clicks a button and onclick calls the JS function

Comment: If the button is a submit button, it will submit the form by default, which reloads the page.

Comment: Nope not a submit button, has a on click  attribute that calls the JS function , that’s it

Comment: You realize that the `<script>` in the response isn't going to be executed, since you're not adding it to the DOM, right? If you want it to be executed, do `$("#someid").html(data);` where `someid` is the ID of the DIV where `PHP CALLED AS PURCHASE BUTTON PRESSED` shold be displayed.